# Custom Floating Action Button with TextView on top of Image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface, floating-action-button

I'm trying to create something similar to the picture. I am using `CoordinatorLayout`, `BottomAppBar` and `BottomNavigation`, but the bottom app bar needs a floating action button to create the cradle around the button.
I need the floating action button to have an image and a text view which I will update programmatically.

Is there a way for this to be achieved without creating an entire custom bottom app bar?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a transparent FAB, and draw on top of it a layout with your custom Image & `TextView`;

Similar to FAB, `app:layout_anchor` & `app:layout_anchorGravity` can be used on the layout to lay it on top of the FAB.

Here is an implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_cutout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/navigation" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/navigation"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:shapeAppearance="@style/roundedimage"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/with_cart1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="99"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="8dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
                app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/white"
                app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_4" />

        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image]